# Ehcache, fast restartable and overflow to disk

Tags: java, ehcache, ehcache-bigmemory

I am using ehcache entreprise 2.7 with big memory. I want to have a cache that overflow to the disk when full AND I want this cache to be persistent through restarts.

My current configuration is that :

```
<cache name="dataservice"
            eternal="true"
            maxEntriesLocalHeap="1"
            overflowToOffHeap="true"
            maxBytesLocalOffHeap="60M">
    <persistence strategy="localRestartable"/>
</cache>
```

This configuration makes the cache persistent through restarts ( and it works very well) but it doesn't seem to overflow to the disk. I really want to use "localRestartable" since it works way better than the old attribute diskPersistent="true". "localRestartable" isn't compatible with the attribute overflowToDisk="true"...

Any idea on how I can make my cache overflowing to the disk??

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this and it is not working with restarts(also it is not enterprise version) BUT, I am using some kind of "cach manager" (own solution) - where I am doing backup of all caches into XML files every 20 sec. If is there any better solution - i would appreciate some advice too.

```
<cache name="dataservice"
   maxElementsInMemory="1000"
   maxElementsOnDisk="10000"
   overflowToDisk="true"
   eternal="true"
   >
 </cache>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 4.1 at least, BigMemory Go + Ehcache Enterprise does not support what you are looking for. If you enable the `localRestartable` option, Ehcache will mirror your memory cache to disk (either synchronously or asynchronously). Note that this is not an "overflow" or "spillover" to disk.

> "localRestartable" — Enables the Fast Restart feature which automatically logs all BigMemory data. This option provides fast restartability with fault tolerant data persistence. (from http://www.terracotta.org/documentation/4.1/bigmemorygo/configuration/fast-restart)